# Ruby on Rails setStyle in rjs template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if someone could provide me with an example of using setStyle in an rjs template?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
page['element'].setStyle(:border=> '1px solid black')
```